# Where to put solution folders in file system?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

In the default location:

```
"C:\Users\[UserName]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects"
```

or:

```
"C:\Development\"
```

or:

```
"D:\Development\"
```

or...

Comment: I vote for S:\olution\Folders

Comment: Hey Jon & Mr. Lizard this IS a question, what's the deal? Not only is it a question but it has an accepted answer so why close it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put them on my "Data" drive, which would be D in your case.  Then, if I need to back up my machine, I can easily backup just the data and not the program files.  Separately, your code should be in source control as well.

Comment: +1 for source control; definitely commit your code.  I've lost whole projects due to hdd failures.

Comment: Second that - source control and separate data drives so if you have to clean-install your OS you don't need to move things and end up losing stuff! (And for backups.)

Answer (score -1):

Never keep Your project on System drive, do not trust windows so much!

Comment: That's a fairly out-of-left-field recommendation.

Comment: Indeed.  While I agree with the recommendation in practice, it would be better phrased as something more like, "Keep your data and your system (OS) installation separate.  That way the data is more easily transferrable to other systems, or the system can be re-installed with less risk to the data."

Comment: All right guys, I'll try to be more polite, descriptive and objective next time

Comment: "Windows" is just as likely to destroy your other partitions as it is the system partition. By the way, that likelihood is zero.